# Akeeba Restored Joomla site redirects from Localhost to Live site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have copied my live website to localhost. I have a component installed and when I click on submit to feed the data it redirects to live site. Any solutions ?

I have edited the configuration.php, .htaccess, htaccess.txt and disabled SEF from global settings still not working it keeps redirecting.

Comment: A quick hack would be to edit your hosts file and add the original domain to resolve to localhost

Comment: can't do that. Site is live and handling customers. I don't want any downtime need to make edits to a component locally. Is there anyway I can extract installation file of component from my Component folder over my Joomla website ?

Comment: public $live_site = 'http://localhost/devfolder I have added this to configuration.php still no resolution.

Comment: Probably you have a link put in your component script